# Bid button not showing

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I am using the Woocommerce simple auction plugin. When I open an action everything is fine, it shows in the default template ....but when I create a custom single product template and assign it to the auction, it doesn't show the Bid option. only shows the Starting Bid price.

I am using ocean wp theme and Elementor as my page builder

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sE5J4.png

Comment: I think you should consult the plugin developer.

Comment: @AkhileshBChandran Where should I  contact woocommerce or elementor support ..?

Comment: No. That plugin seems to be developed by a third party. Neither Woocommerce nor Elementor. So you have to contact them.